# previous data stored in list changes as others is appended

Tags: python

**TL;DR**
When I append (or insert) data, the 'wrong data' gets appended, also previous stored data in the list seems to change.

I'm facing a very weird bug in my code, that really makes no sense to me.

I have a CSV file being read and it's data is stored as a list (`ratio`), from that list I use `np.mean()` and `np.std()` to calculate mean and standart deviation and also store them in lists. During those calculations I call a function to check a lot of things, but the important thing is:

When there is a change of status the function will return a list (called `status` where the first item is 1. If there were no status change the return will also be a list, but the first item is 0. **Everything here works so far.**

So I decided to add to a new list (called `crossed`) all the returns (from mentioned function) that indicated a status change, so `if status[0] == 1:`  However the data being added to the list is not the expected.

**Please note this:** I added a `print(status)` just bellow the check if `status[0] == 1`: and it returns as expected, the very next line is a `.append(status)`, and it simply doesn't append what it prints.

```
status = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
crossed = []
for i in range((len(ratio)-periods+1)):
    if i == 0: #Workaround: When i = 0, ratio[-periods-0:0] won't work
        mean.append(np.mean(ratio[-periods-i:]))
        std.append(np.std(ratio[-periods-i:])) 
        lower_std.append(mean[-1]-std[-1])          
        status = check_ratio(ratio[-periods],mean[-1],lower_std[-1],i,status)           
        if status[0] == 1:
            crossed.append(status)
    else:
        mean.append(np.mean(ratio[-periods-i:-i]))
        std.append(np.std(ratio[-periods-i:-i]))
        lower_std.append(mean[-1]-std[-1])
        status = check_ratio(ratio[-periods-i],mean[-1],lower_std[-1],i,status)
        if status[0] == 1:
            print (status)
            crossed.append(status)

print(crossed)
```

The check_ratio() function returns a list with a lot of data, but the first item is ALWAYS either 0 or 1.
The `print(status)` return is this: (**Note how EVERY list starts with 1, as expected**)

```
[1, 1, 54, 1.138758865248227, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979]
[1, 2, 57, 1.1353429985855727, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979]
[1, 3, 68, 1.1337522123893804, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979]
[1, -1, 78, 1.1309345594525235, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 127, 1.130847142192477, 1.1304628293233858, 1.1294503731447396, 1.1284379169660932]
[1, 2, 131, 1.1303973913355072, 1.1304628293233858, 1.1294503731447396, 1.1284379169660932]
[1, 0, 135, 1.1335466666666667, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 138, 1.1308163809185396, 1.1296433002012238, 1.128433107660401, 1.1272229151195785]
[1, 2, 139, 1.1282648093529015, 1.1296433002012238, 1.128433107660401, 1.1272229151195785]
[1, -1, 140, 1.1270390684629994, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 142, 1.1255687149255582, 1.1256917189689608, 1.1233910776545415, 1.1210904363401222]
[1, 2, 143, 1.1254230680630128, 1.1256917189689608, 1.1233910776545415, 1.1210904363401222]
[1, 3, 150, 1.1225412014885698, 1.1256917189689608, 1.1233910776545415, 1.1210904363401222]
[1, -1, 154, 1.1210447814197948, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 197, 1.1171276991444958, 1.1161855800851872, 1.1132670986656799, 1.1103486172461723]
[1, 2, 198, 1.1127123608670182, 1.1161855800851872, 1.1132670986656799, 1.1103486172461723]
[1, 0, 203, 1.1246100837937574, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 284, 1.1390154874100347, 1.1381523185174933, 1.1368941197303815, 1.1356359209432696]
[1, 0, 287, 1.1418469131706104, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 292, 1.137294829075651, 1.136934972982161, 1.1354744212606314, 1.134013869539102]
[1, 0, 297, 1.1415675686816016, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 405, 1.135509186838826, 1.1350790378560178, 1.1335324241438416, 1.1319858104316656]
[1, 2, 407, 1.1339004993526909, 1.1350790378560178, 1.1335324241438416, 1.1319858104316656]
[1, 3, 414, 1.1330645161290323, 1.1350790378560178, 1.1335324241438416, 1.1319858104316656]
[1, 0, 429, 1.1365694764439502, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 442, 1.1273146097280056, 1.1267225301265933, 1.1244185615555562, 1.1221145929845189]
[1, 0, 443, 1.1352307739239194, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 487, 1.1294793579340165, 1.1275050776354896, 1.1255123932368172, 1.1235197088381448]
[1, 0, 490, 1.1343246592317224, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 507, 1.1273536042898056, 1.1260499911131632, 1.1238715385874056, 1.121693086061648]
[1, 2, 509, 1.1253301757901448, 1.1260499911131632, 1.1238715385874056, 1.121693086061648]
[1, 0, 521, 1.1303555916720376, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 526, 1.1238224560807943, 1.120965441404663, 1.1181032018014265, 1.11524096219819]
[1, 0, 528, 1.1290014064697609, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 580, 1.1282299098894226, 1.1262199790650198, 1.1233324063904733, 1.1204448337159267]
[1, 2, 586, 1.1258169934640523, 1.1262199790650198, 1.1233324063904733, 1.1204448337159267]
[1, 3, 599, 1.1229769929859992, 1.1262199790650198, 1.1233324063904733, 1.1204448337159267]
[1, 0, 605, 1.131025825922068, 0, 0, 0]
```

Now this is the `print(crossed)` return:

```
[[0, 3, 68, 1.1337522123893804, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979], 
[0, 3, 68, 1.1337522123893804, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979], 
[0, 3, 68, 1.1337522123893804, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979], 
[1, -1, 78, 1.1309345594525235, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 2, 131, 1.1303973913355072, 1.1304628293233858, 1.1294503731447396, 1.1284379169660932], 
[0, 2, 131, 1.1303973913355072, 1.1304628293233858, 1.1294503731447396, 1.1284379169660932], 
[1, 0, 135, 1.1335466666666667, 0, 0, 0], 
[1, 2, 139, 1.1282648093529015, 1.1296433002012238, 1.128433107660401, 1.1272229151195785], 
[1, 2, 139, 1.1282648093529015, 1.1296433002012238, 1.128433107660401, 1.1272229151195785], 
[1, -1, 140, 1.1270390684629994, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 3, 150, 1.1225412014885698, 1.1256917189689608, 1.1233910776545415, 1.1210904363401222], 
[0, 3, 150, 1.1225412014885698, 1.1256917189689608, 1.1233910776545415, 1.1210904363401222], 
[0, 3, 150, 1.1225412014885698, 1.1256917189689608, 1.1233910776545415, 1.1210904363401222], 
[1, -1, 154, 1.1210447814197948, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 2, 198, 1.1127123608670182, 1.1161855800851872, 1.1132670986656799, 1.1103486172461723], 
[0, 2, 198, 1.1127123608670182, 1.1161855800851872, 1.1132670986656799, 1.1103486172461723], 
[1, 0, 203, 1.1246100837937574, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 284, 1.1390154874100347, 1.1381523185174933, 1.1368941197303815, 1.1356359209432696], 
[1, 0, 287, 1.1418469131706104, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 292, 1.137294829075651, 1.136934972982161, 1.1354744212606314, 1.134013869539102], 
[1, 0, 297, 1.1415675686816016, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 3, 414, 1.1330645161290323, 1.1350790378560178, 1.1335324241438416, 1.1319858104316656], 
[0, 3, 414, 1.1330645161290323, 1.1350790378560178, 1.1335324241438416, 1.1319858104316656], 
[0, 3, 414, 1.1330645161290323, 1.1350790378560178, 1.1335324241438416, 1.1319858104316656], 
[1, 0, 429, 1.1365694764439502, 0, 0, 0], 
[1, 1, 442, 1.1273146097280056, 1.1267225301265933, 1.1244185615555562, 1.1221145929845189], 
[1, 0, 443, 1.1352307739239194, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 1, 487, 1.1294793579340165, 1.1275050776354896, 1.1255123932368172, 1.1235197088381448], 
[1, 0, 490, 1.1343246592317224, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 2, 509, 1.1253301757901448, 1.1260499911131632, 1.1238715385874056, 1.121693086061648], 
[0, 2, 509, 1.1253301757901448, 1.1260499911131632, 1.1238715385874056, 1.121693086061648],
[1, 0, 521, 1.1303555916720376, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 526, 1.1238224560807943, 1.120965441404663, 1.1181032018014265, 1.11524096219819], 
[1, 0, 528, 1.1290014064697609, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 3, 599, 1.1229769929859992, 1.1262199790650198, 1.1233324063904733, 1.1204448337159267], 
[0, 3, 599, 1.1229769929859992, 1.1262199790650198, 1.1233324063904733, 1.1204448337159267], 
[0, 3, 599, 1.1229769929859992, 1.1262199790650198, 1.1233324063904733, 1.1204448337159267], 
[1, 0, 605, 1.131025825922068, 0, 0, 0]]
```

They are supposed to match perfectly, but just a few entrys actually matches and somehow some of the data got duplicated (see lines 1,2,3 also 5,6 and 8,9 from the print(crossed)) How can that be possible? It literally prints the line that is supposed to be appended, and appends another line.

So I decided to try asking for a print everytime something get's appended, and it got really wierd.

```
status = check_ratio(ratio[-periods-i],mean[-1],lower_std[-1],i,status)
if status[0] == 1:
    crossed.append(status)
    print('>> Appended:',crossed[-1])
    print(crossed)
```

I cutted the return to the first few lines and the last. Here is what I observed:

- First line is right (`status[0]==1`) and is appended ok
- Second line is right, but the first line (previously appended) got REPLACED by 2 copys of the second line (how?)
- Third line is right, but the previous data got replaced by 3 copys of the 3rd line (Same behavior of second line)
- Fourth line is right, BUT the previous data **DIDN'T GOT REPLACED**, however the first item of each (previous entrys) changed to 0. (See the list under the 4th append)

By the end of this I get a list that makes no sense.

```
Appended: [1, 1, 54, 1.138758865248227, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979]
[[1, 1, 54, 1.138758865248227, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979]]
Appended: [1, 2, 57, 1.1353429985855727, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979]
[[1, 2, 57, 1.1353429985855727, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979], [1, 2, 57, 1.1353429985855727, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979]]
Appended: [1, 3, 68, 1.1337522123893804, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979]
[[1, 3, 68, 1.1337522123893804, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979], [1, 3, 68, 1.1337522123893804, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979], [1, 3, 68, 1.1337522123893804, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979]]
Appended: [1, -1, 78, 1.1309345594525235, 0, 0, 0]
[[0, 3, 68, 1.1337522123893804, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979], [0, 3, 68, 1.1337522123893804, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979], [0, 3, 68, 1.1337522123893804, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979], [1, -1, 78, 1.1309345594525235, 0, 0, 0]]
Appended: [1, 1, 127, 1.130847142192477, 1.1304628293233858, 1.1294503731447396, 1.1284379169660932]
[[0, 3, 68, 1.1337522123893804, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979], [0, 3, 68, 1.1337522123893804, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979], [0, 3, 68, 1.1337522123893804, 1.136314650125257, 1.1337690420509274, 1.1312234339765979], [1, -1, 78, 1.1309345594525235, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 127, 1.130847142192477, 1.1304628293233858, 1.1294503731447396, 1.1284379169660932]]
Appended: [1, 2, 131, 1.1303973913355072, 1.1304628293233858, 1.1294503731447396, 1.1284379169660932]
```

It really makes 0 sense to me. Can someone see what is triggering this weird behavior?

Comment: What is `check_ratio` returning?

Comment: Does `check_ratio` mutate `status`?

Comment: @jmunsch The `check_ratio` return is store in `status` and it's printed, the first printed list.

Comment: @snakecharmerb The `check_ratio` returns a new list everytime, that list is stored in `status` and printed (if status[0] ==1). So yes, it mutates but the return is visible

Comment: The `status` that you are passing to `check_ratio` is the list that was appended to `crossed`  in the previous iteration, so if it's changed in `check_ratio` it will be changed in `crossed` too.  Do you get the same problem is you pass a _copy_ of `status` to `check_ratio` ?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Ohhh right, now it makes sense. .copy() Did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a list (or other mutable container) is added to a list, and the list is later mutated the mutation will be applied to the container as well, as it's the same list.  If there is a risk of later mutation, pass (or store) copies of the list to prevent this kind of problem (known as aliasing).

```
# A function that accepts a list and changes it
>>> def f(sts):
...     sts[-1] = sts[-1] * 2
...     return [x for x in sts]
... 
>>> sts = [1]
>>> out = []
# Observe how the _out_ list is not what we expect (ascending powers of two)
>>> for i in range(5):
...     sts = f(sts)
...     out.append(sts)
...     print(out)
... 
[[2]]
[[4], [4]]
[[4], [8], [8]]
[[4], [8], [16], [16]]
[[4], [8], [16], [32], [32]]


# If we pass a copy of sts, we get the expected output.
>>> sts = [1]
>>> out = []
>>> for i in range(5):
...     sts = f(sts[:])
...     out.append(sts)
...     print(out)
... 
[[2]]
[[2], [4]]
[[2], [4], [8]]
[[2], [4], [8], [16]]
[[2], [4], [8], [16], [32]]
```